# SSRS Report Viewer Device Info PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, printing, reportviewer

**Problem**

We need to print PDF interactively, similarly to print button on the ReportViewer toolbar. Using JavaScript to print PDF proved to be challenging in IE 11, there is no good way to know when PDF file is ready.

Browsing the web I found that you can add open action to PDF to invoke print when it's opened. In SSRS 2016 we could pass

```
<DeviceInfo>
    <PrintOnOpen>true</PrintOnOpen>
</DeviceInfo>
```

to get it working. But this is not working in SSRS 2012.

**Question:**

Is there are option in SSRS 2012 to create PDF with open action to print?

**System Requirements:**

- SQL Server 2012
- SQL Server Reporting Services 2012
- IE 11
- Acrobat Reader

Comment: You could always edit the resultant pdf using something like iText.

Comment: This pdf files get very large, to use other libraries I would need to load it into memory. Currently we using stream and flushing it to the browser.

Comment: iText does not require you to load the full PDF into memory.  I frequently deal with 10,000 page PDFs which are 100's of MB in size (not from SSRS, since it seems to fail around 2k pages, but still).  Obviously if you can do it in SSRS without a post-edit, that is preferable - but if not, you still have options.  (`System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, size)` will avoid hitting disk unless the file is so large as to require it.)